# Part of an undefined function in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, evaluation, hold

I am trying to numerically integrate a system of nonlinear differential equations.

Say for simplicity it is $\dot x_1 = x_2, \dot x_2 = (1-x_1) x_2$.  I hand this to `NDSolve` as

```
NDSolve[{X'[t] == { X[t][[2]], (1-X[t][[1]])X[t][[2]] }, X[0] == {1,1} }, X[t], {t,0,1}]
```

However I run into a problem as `X[t][[1]]` evaluates to `t` and `NDsolve` integrates the different equation $\dot x_1 = x_2, \dot x_2 = (1-t) x_2$.

Is their a simple way around this problem? More generally is their a way to stop `Part` from taking function arguments, but instead to only act as a vector index?

I know in this case I could just write system explicitly, but in the case I am studying the dimensionality of the system is not known when writing the code, and we have `X'[t] == f[X[t]]` where `f` is a function that returns a vector of nonlinear combinations of the parts of `X[t]` according to a pattern. `Hold` prevents `Part` evaluating (which is good) however it also prevents `f`evaluating (which is bad).

Comment: Try `NDSolve[{x'[t] == {Indexed[x[t], 2], (1 - Indexed[x[t], 1]) Indexed[x[t], 2]}, x[0] == {1, 1}}, x, {t, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: Gar, that looks like basic knowledge I should have had, but it has made my life so much easier. If you put it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As J.M. pointed it out, if you want to refer to variables of a vectorial ODE, use `Indexed` as the symbolic counterpart of `Part`.

```
NDSolve[{
     x'[t] == {Indexed[x[t], 2], (1 - Indexed[x[t], 1]) Indexed[x[t], 2]},     
     x[0] == {1, 1}}, x, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Note, that it is the initial condition that explicitly tells `NDSolve` that the dynamical system is vector-valued.